# How do I check which Jupyter notebook has "%run" another notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-module

I have a Jupyter notebook(`parent.ipynb`) which runs another notebook(`child.ipynb`) inside it.

Is there a way to get the filename of the parent file from inside the child file? My child file has a logger and therefore can be called by multiple files. It needs to know which file is calling the logger to create log records and therefore I was wondering if there is any `magic` or any sort of method that can help me with this.

Basically,

### A.ipynb

`[1] %run B.ipynb`

### B.ipynb

`-- insert code that can print parent filename when called --`

Answer (score -1):

add header inside the parent file as follow:

```
import child
```